# python cannot find GL

Tags: python, opengl

Trying to use `pyglet1.2alpha1` under FreeBSD with `python3.3` on an amd64 machine, I get

```
$ python ~/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/gl/gl_info.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 111, in load_library
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Shared object "GL" not found, required by "python"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[…]
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 118, in load_library
    if ((self.linux_not_found_error not in o.message) and
AttributeError: 'OSError' object has no attribute 'message'
```

I have tested my Mesa installation by running `glxgears` (works), I have tried installing `PyOpenGL` for comparison (which does not work, because it depends on the PIL, which is not fit for python3.3), and just to make sure I have reinstalled `python3.3` after installing the `mesa-demos` and `freeglut`, and still no change.

In `python2.7`, I get the same error

```
OSError: Shared object "GL" not found, required by "python2"
```

(without the problem of `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred`), also after installing `PyOpenGL` (which works as expected).

What is the problem here? How do get `pyglet` to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various python files that come with `pyglet` and try to load external resources test explicitly if they run on linux. Consequently, they don't evaluate to the right things on FreeBSD. When replacing `sys.platform.startswith('linux')` with `sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('freebsd')` in the files listed below, it seems to work.

```
pyglet/lib.py
pyglet/app/base.py
pyglet/gl/__init__.py
pyglet/image/codecs/__init__.py
pyglet/input/__init__.py
pyglet/media/drivers/openal/__init__.py
```